# iPhone trying to use a block animation to simulate a card flip, but nothing happens no animation

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to do a card flip animation...but nothing happens.

this is what I do
1. create a container view, to hold the two views to animate from.
2. Create the first view.
3. add it to the container.
4. create the second view
3. start the animation block, beginAnimations
4. call setAnimationTransition put in the view container
5. add the second view to the view container
6. commit the animation,

my code

```
// create container view
CGRect  viewRect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100);
UIView* myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];

// create 2 viues to flip between for animation
UIImage *i= [ UIImage imageNamed : @"card1.jpg"];
UIImageView *topCard=[ [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: i ];
topCard.frame= CGRectMake(0,0,100,100);
[myView addSubview:topCard];
[self.view addSubview:myView];

i= [ UIImage imageNamed : @"card2.jpg"];
UIImageView *butCard=[ [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: i ];
butCard.frame= CGRectMake(0,0,100,100);

// set up the animation
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Flip Top Card" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:NO];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut ];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:myView cache:YES];
[myView addSubview:butCard];

// start the animation
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

-Ted

Comment: To solve it like this you probably have to use a key frame animation or several animations. Remember that you want to change things when the card have flipped half way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is iOS 4.0 or later you can do:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:myView
                  duration:0.3f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                animations:^(void) {
                  self.topCardIsShown = !self.topCardIsShown;
                  self.topCard.hidden = !self.topCardIsShown;
                  self.butCard.hidden = self.topCardIsShown;
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                  // nothing
                }];
```

This assumes that you have added both card views to the myView and have added a `@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL topCardIsShown;` to your class.

Comment: If you don't want the property you could probably also "reuse" the `hidden` property of the image views. `self.topCard.hidden = !self.topCard.hidden; self.butCard.hidden = self.topCard.hidden;` but that is maybe a bit cryptic.